Including user groups in the ID/access token for a Google OIDC app
I have a Google OIDC app. I would like it to return, as a claim in the ID and/or access token, a list of the Workspace groups that a user is a member of. I only want a list of the groups, and do not want permission to edit the groups.
While this seems like it should be simple, as group membership is often used for permission management, I cannot seem to find a way to do this. I've tried adding the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.groups scope to my request (and added it to the application), but there is no additional claim provided in the received token. I cannot find any other scope that would be relevant; there's the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups claim, but that grants write permissions as well.
Even with this scope included in the App's scopes and included in the auth request, the /userinfo endpoint doesn't return the user's groups either.
Is there any way to include a list of the user's Workspace groups in the ID/Access token, without granting any write permissions?
As a bonus question, is there a way to include user roles in a similar manner? I'm coming from an Azure AD/Entra world where groups and roles are easily included as claims in the tokens.

As far as I'm aware it's not currently supported. There's an open issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133774835?pli=1
